# How to access object url outside of templates?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a `FileField` which users upload Excel files to. I need to get access to the URL of the file to use in a helper function; namely `pd.readexcel(url)`.

Currently I am getting the last uploaded object like this:

```
tips_by_employee_report = StoreReports.objects.latest('tips_by_employee_report')
```

I have tried `.url` and `.path` but these methods do not work on this class. I have looked all around and in the Django docs but can only find accessing the `url` in the templates.

How do I access the object URL outside of templates?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario you would be accessing the `StoreReport` object which is:

a.) the last object created `.latest()`

and

b.) filtered for the attribute of `tips_by_employee_report`

Therefore, to access the object's attribute's URL you need to write...

```
tips_by_employee_report.tips_by_employee_report.url
```

...on the next line. Feels a little odd but that's just how it is.